# What's the difference between java.util.Map.putAll(Map<>) and java.util.Map.put(Integer, Object) in a loop

Tags: java, collections, immutability

In the code below, I found that using the putAll method can cause problems if we pass the map in parameter

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String...strings ) {
        Etudiant e1=new  Etudiant(5, "A");
        Etudiant e2=new  Etudiant(6, "B");

        Map<Integer, Etudiant> map= new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, e1);
        map.put(2, e2);

        Map<Integer, Etudiant> map2= new HashMap<>();
        map2.put(1,map.get(1));
        map2.put(1,map.get(2));

        changeMe(map2);
        System.out.println(map.get(1));

        Map<Integer, Etudiant> map3= new HashMap<>();
        map3.putAll(map);
        changeMe(map3);
        System.out.println(map.get(1));
    }

    private static void changeMe(Map<Integer, Etudiant> etudiants) {
        etudiants.get(1).name="K";
    }
}
}
```

Here is the ouput result:

```
Etudiant [age=5, name=A]
Etudiant [age=5, name=K]
```

Could you explain the difference ?

Why after the use of putAll the object changes ?

Comment: What does *"can cause problems"* mean? What problem do you perceive you have? Why do you believe so?

Comment: The object changes because you call changeMe(), which gets the object in the map and changes it. I don't get why you're surprised. What else do you expect, and why?

Comment: In `map2` you add the 2 students to the SAME key, so only the second if kept, so you change student 2 and not student 1, that's why

Comment: map2.put(**1**,map.get(2)); should be map2.put(**2**,map.get(2));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Your code explained in detail

```
Etudiant e1=new  Etudiant(5, "A");
Etudiant e2=new  Etudiant(6, "B");

Map<Integer, Etudiant> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, e1);
map.put(2, e2);
```

`map` now contains `{1=Etudiant(5, "A"), 2=Etudiant(6, "B")}`

```
Map<Integer, Etudiant> map2= new HashMap<>();
map2.put(1,map.get(1));
map2.put(1,map.get(2));
```

`map2` now contains `{1=Etudiant(6, "B")}`

```
changeMe(map2);
System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

`Etudiant(6, "B")` has been **renamed** `Etudiant(6, "K")`, so:
`map` now contains `{1=Etudiant(5, "A"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}`
`map2` now contains `{1=Etudiant(6, "K")}`
and it printed:

> Etudiant(5, "A")

```
Map<Integer, Etudiant> map3= new HashMap<>();
map3.putAll(map);
```

`map3` content is a copy of `map` content, so:
`map3` now contains `{1=Etudiant(5, "A"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}`

```
changeMe(map3);
System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

`Etudiant(5, "A")` has been **renamed** `Etudiant(5, "K")`, so:
`map` now contains `{1=Etudiant(5, "K"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}`
`map2` now contains `{1=Etudiant(6, "K")}`
`map3` now contains `{1=Etudiant(5, "K"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}`
and it printed:

> Etudiant(5, "K")

The code works exactly the way you coded it to do.

---

All the above can easily be seen by adding a bunch of print statements, which is one way to **debug** your code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Etudiant e1=new  Etudiant(5, "A");
        Etudiant e2=new  Etudiant(6, "B");

        Map<Integer, Etudiant> map= new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, e1);
        map.put(2, e2);
        System.out.println("map:  " + map);

        Map<Integer, Etudiant> map2= new HashMap<>();
        map2.put(1,map.get(1));
        map2.put(1,map.get(2));
        System.out.println("map2: " + map2);

        changeMe(map2);
        System.out.println("map:  " + map);
        System.out.println("map2: " + map2);
        System.out.println(map.get(1));

        Map<Integer, Etudiant> map3= new HashMap<>();
        map3.putAll(map);
        System.out.println("map3: " + map3);

        changeMe(map3);
        System.out.println("map:  " + map);
        System.out.println("map2: " + map2);
        System.out.println("map3: " + map3);
        System.out.println(map.get(1));
    }
    private static void changeMe(Map<Integer, Etudiant> etudiants) {
        System.out.print("Renamed " + etudiants.get(1));
        etudiants.get(1).name="K";
        System.out.println(" to " + etudiants.get(1));
    }
}
class Etudiant {
    int id;
    String name;
    Etudiant(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Etudiant(" + this.id + ", \"" + this.name + "\")";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
map:  {1=Etudiant(5, "A"), 2=Etudiant(6, "B")}
map2: {1=Etudiant(6, "B")}
Renamed Etudiant(6, "B") to Etudiant(6, "K")
map:  {1=Etudiant(5, "A"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}
map2: {1=Etudiant(6, "K")}
Etudiant(5, "A")
map3: {1=Etudiant(5, "A"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}
Renamed Etudiant(5, "A") to Etudiant(5, "K")
map:  {1=Etudiant(5, "K"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}
map2: {1=Etudiant(6, "K")}
map3: {1=Etudiant(5, "K"), 2=Etudiant(6, "K")}
Etudiant(5, "K")
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in `map2`:

```
Map<Integer, Etudiant> map2= new HashMap<>();
map2.put(1,map.get(1));
map2.put(1,map.get(2));
```

You overwrite the first element so the map is:

```
[1, e2]
```

So then when you call `changeMe()`, it is changing `e2`, *not* `e1`, so when you print `e1`, it will remain unchanged. Then when you call `putAll()` it will actually change the first element and the change will be reflected.

From the docs for [`Map::putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)):

> The effect of this call is equivalent to that of calling `put(k, v)` on this map once for each mapping from key k to value v in the specified map.

So the two are equivalent

---

Change your code to:

```
Map<Integer, Etudiant> map2= new HashMap<>();
map2.put(1,map.get(1));
map2.put(2,map.get(2));
```

And you should get the expected results

Answer (score 1):

Both `putAll` and a series of `put` will achieve the same result. But depending on the Map implementation, `putAll` can sometimes be more faster. For instance, if the writes to the map need to acquire a lock, then `putAll` can acquire the lock once and use it for all locks. Or if a map has to perform some internal maintenance or accounting between writes, it can optimize those as well.

It's also a nice one-liner if you already have a collection at hand, so it's less verbose than a loop.